# Gitolite local working copy for Apache DocumentRoot

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite, working-copy

I have a system setup with git and gitolite.  All is working well, except I want my structure to be like this:

Local Environment -> Development Server -> Production Server

I have a repo setup on the dev server, and it's successfully cloned down to the local environment.  Now, what I need is a local filesystem working copy on the development server but I'm not sure how to do this with gitolite.

```
git clone /home/gitolote/repositories/myrepo.git
```

Works fine until I try to push/pull, at which point I get this:

```
remote: ENV GL_RC not set
remote: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hooks/update line 20.
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

Any ideas on how to do this with gitolite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the [local protocol](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html) for your clone, which means you are bypassing gitolite entirely (the gitolite script is called through a [ssh forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858)).

You should make a second clone on your development server, using a gitolite compatible address like:

```
git clone git@gitoliteserver:myrepo.git
```

That second repo would be able to push/pull to/from the gitolite server, while providing the "local filesystem working copy" on the development server you are after.

Comment: Thanks.  It was weird setting up a public key for the local user account but all worked out in the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you require using the [local protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html), all you need is to set `GL_BYPASS_UPDATE_HOOK` environment variable to `1`:

```
gorgo@somegitoliteserver:~/testing$ GL_BYPASS_UPDATE_HOOK=1 git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 3 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 234 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
To file:///home/gitolite/repositories/testing.git/
96be337..ab5ca6d  master -> master
```